# Python to scan string which consists of various other strings

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have a huge string which actually contains lots of other substrings. When I am running my code it's not able to scan the string properly and returns false value.

Goal: I am trying to search specific value in string and want to store it in to variable.

```
Code`import re
mystring = "This 'is' the 'test' I am doing"
searchObj = re.search( r'(.*) test (.*?) .*', mystring, re.M|re.I)

if searchObj:
   print "searchObj.group() : ", searchObj.group()
   print "searchObj.group(1) : ", searchObj.group(1)
   print "searchObj.group(2) : ", searchObj.group(2)
else:
   print "Null"`
```

Effort: I have gone through various regex tutorials and tried various different way in which scanning simple string like "This is the test I am doing" is success but if the string is having substring wouldn't work.

New to python and regex any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**This Should Work.**

**REGEXP:**

```
(\')
```

**Replace:**

```
"'" => ""
```

**Python Code:**

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"(\')"

test_str = "This 'is' the 'test' I am doing"

subst = ""

# You can manually specify the number of replacements by changing the 4th argument
result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE)

if result:
    print (result)

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

**Then variable = result**

**See:** https://regex101.com/r/wuFeG9/3
**Test Python Code:** http://ideone.com/0IGz1Q

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

mystring = "This 'is' the 'test' I am doing"
searchObj = re.search( r"(.*)'?test'?(.*)", mystring, re.M|re.I)

if searchObj:
   print ("searchObj.group() : ", searchObj.group())
   print ("searchObj.group(1) : ", searchObj.group(1))
   print ("searchObj.group(2) : ", searchObj.group(2))
else:
   print ("Null")

>>> searchObj.group() :  This 'is' the 'test' I am doing
>>> searchObj.group(1) :  This 'is' the '
>>> searchObj.group(2) :   I am doing
```